# Check if item is in cart using categories

Tags: cartthrob

Folks:

The client has a number of products that do not ship outside of North America (most ship anywhere). I am using the is_in_cart tag (http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/is_in_cart/) to check if non-shippable items are in the cart. There are 18 items that don't ship outside North America.

Now, I have a long OR statement to deal with this ({exp:cartthrob:is_in_cart entry_id="301"} OR {exp:cartthrob:is_in_cart entry_id="302"} OR {exp:cartthrob:is_in_cart entry_id="303"} etc.). This isn't too bad. Problem is, though, that the site is going multilingual. This means 18 more checks for every new language. With 6 languages total, that's a crazy number of OR statements and will be a big performance hit.

It would be great if I could just check against a single category. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you use for example publisher for translations, you will keep the same ID's so that would not be an issue!

What I would do in your case is add a custom field to the product of the type checkbox and check the products that can't be shipped. Then in you loop through your cart to check if a product is in the cart you can do a conditional check on the custom check box field.

I don't know if it is possible with cartthrob to add custom fields, with expresso store you can since those product entries are based on channels.

Comment: It's definitely possible in Cartthrob - products also go in channels in CT.  Indeed, you can have as many product channels as you like, with basically any differing set of fields you like.